# QComboBox not aligning to right

Tags: c++, qt, layout, combobox

I have a `QHBoxLayout` and i want to add some children to the right, and other to the left:

```
label = new QLabel(...);
layout->addItem(label);
layout->setAlignment(label, Qt::AlignLeft);
select = new QComboBox(...);
layout->addItem(select);
layout->setAlignment(select, Qt::AlignRight);
```

However `select` is not been aligned to the right... any idea?

Neither with `QCheckBox` and `QLabel`, but works properly using `QSlider`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QHBoxLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
QLabel * label = new QLabel("this is label");
layout->addWidget(label, Qt::AlignLeft);
layout->setAlignment(label, Qt::AlignLeft);
QComboBox * select = new QComboBox(this);
layout->addWidget(select);
layout->setAlignment(select, Qt::AlignRight);
```

[image: Result of that above code]

Comment: thank you , it was my fault, i was doing `layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft)`